# Why do renderer fs.existsSync, fs.readfileSync (declared in preload.js) return 'undefined'?

Tags: node.js, electron

Recommended practice aside, `fs` functions execute in Electron renderer script with `nodeIntegration 'true'`, `contextIsolation 'false'`.

Complementing these webPreference settings and applying 'preload.js' to establish the context bridge, `invoke`, `send` and `on` perform as expected - but `existsSync` and `readFileSync` (existing as `window.api` function objects) return `undefined`.

Are `fs` functions not supported across `contextBridge`, or are the declarations below incorrect?

```
process.once('loaded', () => {
    const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
    const fs = require('fs')
    const validChannels = ['requestChan', 'controlChan', 'displayChan', 'previewTxChan', 'previewRxChan']
    contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('api', {
        async invoke(channel, ...params) {
            if (validChannels.includes(channel))
                return await ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, ...params)
        },
        async send(channel, ...params) {
            if (validChannels.includes(channel))
                return ipcRenderer.send(channel, ...params)
        },
        on(channel, callback) {
            if (validChannels.includes(channel))
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, callback)
        },
        existsSync(path) {
            fs.existsSync(path)
        },
        readFileSync(path) {
            fs.readFileSync(path)
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What version of Electron are you on and what does a simplified version of your main script look like? (particularly interested in the window configurations)

Comment: Electron 18.3.0; first step to overcoming this was to correct the careless error to include 'return' as shown:

Comment: ```    existsSync(path) {
                  return fs.existsSync(path)
                },
    readFileSync(path) {
                  return fs.readFileSync(path)
                }
```

Comment: But this renderer code snippet fails with error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_URL:

Comment: ```            console.log('Opening', logoPath)
            let base64LogoImg = window.api.readFileSync(logoPath).toString('base64')
            let logoHtmlString = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + base64LogoImg +
                                 '" width=100% height=100%"/>'
```

Comment: Nothing unusual in window configs; both declare webPreferences:{nodeIntegration:false,contextIsolation:true,preload:path.resolve(app.getAppPath(),'preload.js')}. All other Main and Renderer functions work as expected (intensive activity), as they (including otherwise identical readfileSync(logoPath).toString('base64')) did prior to implementing contextBridge

Comment: There is evidently a bug associated with preload declaration readFileSync(path) { return fs.readFileSync(path) }, unless I misunderstand usage. Without contextIsolation, applying const fs = require ('fs') in the renderer and invoking fs.readFileSync(logoPath).toString('base64'), the assigned base64LogoImg has length 69436 and the image is correctly rendered. With contextIsolation however, base64LogoImg has incorrect length 171056, although appearing as a base64 string (in devTools or Main console if sent and reported).

Comment: Restating the issue, the returned base64 string with contextIsolation is invalid, unable to be rendered by insertAdjacentHTML or innerHTML (both methods report identical error) ```console.log('Opening', logoPath); let base64LogoImg = window.api.readFileSync(logoPath).toString('base64'); let logoHtmlString = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + base64LogoImg + '" width=100% height=100%"/>'; control.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', logoHtmlString);```

Comment: It's confirmed that 'logoPath', and content of the target PNG file is unchanged.

Comment: Electron 19.0.7 (latest) exhibits the same failure.

Comment: Further investigation indicates the problem lies with the ```toString``` method applied under context isolation; logging the file read synchronously (```readFileSync```) or by callback (```readFile```) reports the correct ```Uint8Array``` length, while ```toString```returns constant incorrect string length (171056) regardless of selected base (hex, base64, ..).

Comment: Indications are that prototype pollution in Plist may be the problem: https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-4cpg-3vgw-4877

Answer (score 0):

It is not `readFileSync` that was the problem, but method `toString('base64')` within context-isolated renderer process.

It is now understood that `toString('base64')` requires the object to be encoded to be of type `Buffer`, which is evidently not passed by `contextBridge` `readFileSync(path)` with correct type into the context-isolated renderer process.

The issue is overcome by wrapping both operations within `preload.js` `contextBridge` as follows:

```
loadImageSync(path) {
    let data = fs.readFileSync(path)
    let base64Image = Buffer.from(data).toString('base64')
    return base64Image
}
```

It would be preferred (for efficiency) to apply `fs.readFile` in the `contextBridge` with renderer callback to perform `toString('base64')`, but the means to make type `Buffer` visible via `contextBridge` is not known.