# How to overcome npm audit fix failure for Electron?

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

This question originates from (the misleading) [Why do renderer fs.existsSync, fs.readfileSync (declared in preload.js) return 'undefined'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72804870/why-do-renderer-fs-existssync-fs-readfilesync-declared-in-preload-js-return), where prototype pollution is strongly indicated as the cause of method `.toString('base64')` failure.

With node v16.15.1, npm v8.11.0 and electron v19.0.7, the following `npm` steps are performed, in order that re-integration of node package `serialport` is accomplished:

1. `rm -r node_modules`
2. `rm package-lock.json`
3. `npm i`

The electron app in question has been stable for many months, revised recently only to effect context isolation by means of `contextBridge` whereon the failure of method `toString('base64')` in a Renderer process strongly indicates prototype pollution, illustrated even by the simple test (in Main process) which prints the given string twice (ie. ineffectual `base64` encoding):

```
let str = 'Many hands make light work';
console.log(str, str.toString('base64');
```

The issue is evidently unrelated to deployment of `contextBridge`, but to an unfortunate coincident Electron eco-system update for which `npm fix audit`, as well as `npm fix audit --force` fails to overcome the reported 18 vulnerabilities (8 moderate, 8 high, 2 critical).

Since many of these report 'Prototype pollution in Plist', how are they to be overcome? Full re-installation of node, npm and electron confirm the same vulnerabilities, again after attempting `npm fix` (with or without `--force` option). Setting `package.json` dependency `"plist": ^3.0.5` has no evident effect.

Expectedly, the development environment is inconsistent on Windows and macOS platforms, with remedy unknown.

If versions should be regressed, please indicate which to use for node, npm and electron (with the condition that the latter should support `contextBridge`).

Comment: Now, I believe this is not a Node/Electron issue. NPM reports the package `plist`, doesn't it? Setting the dependency's version to `^3.0.5` won't do anything, since that's the latest version published on NPM. Have you tried removing the dependency (temporarily) and/or contacting the package's developers? However, since the current version is from last year, they might already have fixed it...

Comment: ```plist``` was included as a dependency only to test if the explicit ^3.0.5 overcomes the issue. It has not previously been an app dependency. The reason I expect ```Node```, ```npm``` or ```electron``` issue is the only-recent failure of ```toString('base64')``` and the concurrently reported ```npm i``` vulnerabilities, listed as follows:

Comment: Prototype pollution in ```dot-prop``` <4.2.1 (high severity); context isolation bypass via leaked cross-connect objects etc in ```electron``` <15.5.4 (high), (even after installing 19.0.7); RegEx DoS in ```glob-parent``` <5.1.2 (high); long list re ```got``` <11.8.5 (moderate); prototype pollution in ```plist``` <3.0.4 (critical) .. misinterpretation of malicious XML input in ```xmldom```, and prototype pollution in ```yargs-parser``` (moderate). All report "fix available via ```npm audit fix```", but that command (with option ```--force``` effects no updates.

Comment: Working perfectly in the past,  ```package.json``` ```"postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"``` invoked during ```npm i``` execution resets ```electron``` dependency to ^6.1.12 before vulnerabilities are reported at completion. ```npm i electron@latest``` corrects the ```electron``` dependency (to ^19.0.7), but the subsequently required three steps (noted in the question above) for ```node serialport``` integration again revert the ```electron``` dependency to ^6.1.12! This appears to be a recursive issue - while the app supported serial and IP comms without issue before.

Comment: Once overcome, the test will be whether ```toString('base64')``` method will work for image display script as before (prior to introducing ```preload.js``` ```contextBridge```)  - or indeed that ```toString``` performs correctly for various arguments (```'hex'``` etc).

Comment: I can't do anything with the NPM output you posted into the comments. However, if you still believe that it's a Node problem, try in the commandline: `node -e "<code>"` However, your code you posted will not transform to Base64, as per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString#parameters). By default, only `Number` and `BigInt` override the `.toString()` method, but take a radix instead of an encoding. What were you actually trying to encode?

Comment: The objective is to read a PNG file within renderer process ('within' for minimum latency). The ```toString('base64')``` method to prepare the ```html``` string worked as expected without ```electron``` ```contextBridge```. Applying ```preload.js``` ```return fs.readFileSync(path)```  with ```contextIsolation``` does indeed make file content available within the renderer process, but '''toString('base64')``` erroneously converts each byte of that argument into an unexpectedly long string of decimal numbers - hence failing to produce renderable ```html``` image data. The full solution follows.

Comment: Incidentally, the Node prototype pollution issues appear to stem from Node re-installation forcing ```package.json``` ```devDependencies``` to rather early releases of ```electron-builder``` (^5.5.0) and ```nodemon``` (^1.3.3)!

Answer (score 0):

It is not prototype pollution of `toString('base64')` giving rise to failure to produce a `base64` string.

The cause of failure is understood to be that the buffer object returned by `fs.readFileSync` (as declared in `preload.js`) comprises an object type (of class `Buffer`) not known to the context-isolated renderer process, and the `toString('base64')` method handles it inappropriately.

If I knew how to make the `Buffer` class prototype visible (`const Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer` is of course not permitted in context-isolated renderer), the solution would be straightforward.

The solution adopted and tested is to declare `loadBase64Image` in `preload.js` as follows:

```
loadbase64Image(path) {
    let data = fs.readFileSync(path);
    base64Image = data.toString('base64');
    return base64Image
}
```

which of course may be collapsed to `return fs.readFileSync(path).toString('base64')` as working in the original renderer with `nodeIntegration: true` and `contextIsolation: false`.

I'm interested to know how an arbitrary class should be declared within `preload.js` so that objects of that type are correctly handled in associated renderer process.